# Reading HTML with out adding to DOM in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

While reading happened to see this code. The response for an ajax call was coming as plain html like this:

```
<div id="connectionId">123444</div>
```

To my surprise they were able to retrieve the value like this:

```
$('<div id="connectionId">123444</div>').text() // output 123444
```

I was under the impression that jQuery can only read those values if it is added to the DOM.

Can someone share some light on this behavior. What am I understanding wrong here ?

> Note: It did not create the div element in the DOM.

Comment: `$('<div id = "connectionId">123444</div>')` creates a jquery DOM element, with an id of `connectionId`, containing the text of `123444`. The DOM element exists and is in memory, it is just not attached to the page's DOM. jQuery can read/manipulate any wrapped DOM element no problem at all, regardless of if it's part of the page's DOM or not.

Comment: [A presentation from John Resig no less](https://johnresig.com/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#0).

Comment: Can u explain me a bit more.?

Comment: jQuery basically creates a new jQuery object using document fragments ( I think), so no need to add them to the DOM for them to work.

Comment: So @Andy the make use of document.createDocumentFragment() to manage ??

Comment: I think so. That presentation I added by JR suggests that JQuery makes extensive use of them.

Comment: That is totally a new information for me and i was not aware of document.createDocumentFragment() itself.Why dont you post this as answer.Can i answer to my own question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161723/discussion-between-sunil-hari-and-andy).

Comment: Please mention the reason for the downvote

Comment: Please be more explicit when you come there with questions. For your question the answer is not, your elements don't have to be in the DOM to be parsed by jQuery. As i explained in the post below, where you press the down vote button just because your question wasn't specific.

Comment: Please read through the comments in this question and read what @Andy had explained.And i don't think the reason you mentioned before is a proper reason for a downvote.Anyways have got the answer that I need from

Comment: cool, enjoy :) .

Answer (score -1):

Is not required to have the element on the DOM.

By simply call this `$("<div class="connectionId">123444</div>").html()` you will get `123444`, but if you wrap the html element into a parent element like `$("<div><div class="connectionId">123444</div></div>").html()` output will be `<div class="connectionId">123444</div>`.

Also you can get the element you want with `find` function.
https://jsfiddle.net/4vamrve7/1/

Comment: Not what am looking for